# how can I upload a pdf and an image in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I am trying to upload a pdf file and an image in php mysql but it seems that the move_uploaded_file function can only work with one file. I have tried to make it work with both files but it doesn't seem to me working. It moves just the images to the target folder and adds both image name and pdf name to the database but it doesn't move the pdf to target folder.  This is the code. pls help

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once("includedfunctions.php");
    include 'dbh.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $author=$_POST['author'];
    $target = "img/pic_book/";
    $target2 = "img/pdf/";
    $imgname = basename($_FILES["cphoto"]["name"]);
    $bookname = basename($_FILES["book"]["name"]);
    $newname = $target.basename($_FILES["cphoto"]["name"]);
    $newname2 = $target2.basename($_FILES["book"]["name"]);
    $img_type = pathinfo($newname,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $book_type = pathinfo($newname2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($img_type!='jpg' && $img_type!='JPG' && $img_type!='png' && $img_type!='PNG'){
        $message="Please ensure you are entering an image";
    }else{
        if($book_type != 'pdf'){
            $message="books must be uploaded in pdf format";    
        }else{
            if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$author)){
                $message = "<p style='color:red'>Please enter the real name of the author; not a nickname.</p>";
            }else{
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cphoto"]["tmp_name"], $newname)) {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["book"]["tmp_name"], $newname2));{
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO books (Title, Author, pathtopdf, pathtoimage) VALUES ('$title', '$author', '$bookname', '$imgname')";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    if($result){
                        $message = "upload successful";
                    }else{
                        $message = "upload failed1";
                    }
                    }       
            }else{
                $message = "upload failed";
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
  $message="";
  $title="";
}
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>Libraria</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/contactcss.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br><br><br><br>
<!-- content -->
<div class="container">
    <?php 
        echo '<p>Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name']. '</p><br>';
        echo '<p>' . $message. ' </p>';
    ?>  
    <br><br>
    <!--form-->
    <div class="row"> 
        <form action="admin2.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <label for="Title">Title</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="fname" value ="<?php echo $title; ?>" name="title" placeholder="Title of the book" required><br>
          <label for="author">Author</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="author" placeholder="Author of the book" required><br>
          <label for="Cover photo">Cover photo</label><br>
          <input type="file" id="cphoto" name="cphoto"  required><br>
          <label for="book">Book</label>
          <input type="file" id="book" name="book" required><br>
          <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit"><b>Upload</b></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you might find that the rouge `;` in this line has something to do with it `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["book"]["tmp_name"], $newname2));{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is all correct. just check pdf size. if size is more than 4MB than it will not allowed to upload. you need to increase upload file size in php.ini file or apache config settting file.

Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

application/pdf is the mime type for pdf not just pdf.

Comment: But OP is not looking at the mime type, just the file extension